# Now to read multiple files of netcdf with this date directory

Tags: python, date, for-loop, directory

I have this file directory as an example and I would like to read all files as a date to date loop
disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov-3B42_Daily.19980101.7.nc4
so the part where the date 1990101 is changing based on the investigated dates
these files are netcdf files 
I know how to read one by one file but I could not make to run the whole file that includes multiple files
as an example 
1- we can read as all files in one folder 
2- read date to date files (preferred)

Comment: What does the input look like? What do you want as output?

Comment: the input is the netcdf files with this directory in one folder the output is not important in this stage however it is going to be as a text file

Comment: Is 'multiaplefiles' a typo of 'multiple files', or is it something else?

Comment: it is a typo it is a multiple files

Comment: disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov-3B42_Daily.19980101.7.nc4 day one
disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov-3B42_Daily.19980102.7.nc4 day two
and so on

Comment: Do you have any examples of code you've tried / you currently have that you could share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the files are incremented by day, you can take advantage of Python's [dateutil rrule function](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) to loop over them easily.

Below is an example of how to loop over daily files in Jan. 1998 and then read them in as you iterate through the days.

```
import netCDF4
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

fl_pfx = 'disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov-3B42_Daily.'
fl_sfx = '.7.nc4'
strt_dt = datetime.date(1998,1,1)
end_dt = datetime.date(1998,1,31)

for day in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=strt_dt, until=end_dt):
    day_fmt = datetime.datetime.strftime(day, '%Y%m%d')
    src_fl = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(fl_pfx, day_fmt, fl_sfx)
    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(src_fl, 'r')
```

Comment: do I have to make a separate directory variable as an example 
directory = 'C:/Users/ma570408/Documents/Dr.WAng/Haiti project/TRMM_Haiti/TRMM3B42/'
os.chdir(directory)
 @N1B4

Comment: I would like to iterate through files while doing some operations such as getting values of certain location or boundary then save them in text files in each line.  So, it would look like 1998.01.01 then values for x and y location in line one. Then it does this for all files with the specific dates chosen.

Comment: @Mrmr please provide the code you have tried so far, we can then give more feedback and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
     from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,cm
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import numpy as np
     from netCDF4 import Dataset
     import arcpy
     import os
     import datetime
     from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
     import netCDF4


     directory = 'C:/Users/ma570408/Documents/Dr.WAng/Haiti project/TRMM_Haiti/TRMM3B42/'
    os.chdir(directory)
     result_array = np.array((0,28))
     fl_pfx = 'disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov-3B42_Daily.'
     fl_sfx = '.7.nc4'
    strt_dt = datetime.date(1998,1,1)
    end_dt = datetime.date(1998,1,3)

for day in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=strt_dt, until=end_dt):
day_fmt = datetime.datetime.strftime(day, '%Y%m%d')
src_fl = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(fl_pfx, day_fmt, fl_sfx)
precip = netCDF4.Dataset(src_fl, 'r')

precip = precip.variables['precipitation']
precip = precip[:]

precip = np.transpose(precip)


#precip.close()

theLats = np.arange(-49.875,50,0.25)
theLons = np.arange(-179.875,180,0.25)

# Set all the missing values less than 0 to NaNs
np.putmask(precip,precip<0,np.nan)
# Plot the figure, define the geographic bounds
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
latcorners = ([17.25,21.25])
loncorners = ([-75.25,-67.57])
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=latcorners[0],urcrnrlat=latcorners[1],llcrnrlon=loncorners[0],urcrnrlon=loncorners[1])
# Draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
# Draw filled contours.
clevs = np.arange(0,100,0.5)
# Define the latitude and longitude data
x, y = np.float32(np.meshgrid(theLons, theLats))
cs  =  m.contourf(x,y,precip,clevs,cmap=cm.GMT_drywet,latlon=True)

parallels = np.arange(-50.,51,25.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True,False,True,False]) 
meridians = np.arange(-180.,180.,60.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[False,False,False,True])

# Set the title and fonts
plt.title('01 Jan 1998 UTC Rain Rate')
font = {'family' : 'normal', 'weight' : 'bold', 'size' : 4}
plt.rc('font', **font)

# Add colorbar
cbar  =  m.colorbar(cs,location='right',pad="5%")
cbar.set_label('mm/day')
#plt.show()


#plt.savefig('testTRMMmap.jpg',dpi=300)
lons=[-72.357027,-72.459848,-72.49067 ,-72.682285,-72.338742,-72.483468,-72.375638,-72.625579 ,-72.621485,-72.689335,-72.701488,-72.334749,-72.081942 ,-72.019022, -71.992917 ,-71.950678 ,-71.841423 ,-72.237008 ,-72.15214,-72.178977,-71.825884,-72.12135,-72.271279,-72.192902,-72.107022,-72.126704,-72.397491,-72.529367]
lats=[19.07039,19.218378,19.025554,19.098092,19.34189,19.490445,19.525487,19.493374,19.355849 ,19.310919,19.258246,18.909316,18.785043,19.144316,18.999588,18.866657,18.746084,18.830828,18.952298,19.188401,19.075994,19.464433,19.5202,19.402877,19.324003,18.66134,18.774135,18.88551]

lons=np.array(lons)
lats=np.array(lats)

py = (lons +180) /0.25
px = (lats +50) /0.25
py=py.tolist()
px=px.tolist()

pixel_value=precip[px,py]

pixel_value=np.array(pixel_value).reshape(1,28)
pixel_value=str(pixel_value)
print (pixel_value)
thefile=open('test.txt','w')
thefile.write(pixel_value)
thefile.close()
```

at this point I am struggling to save my output to a text file with each line having one row and 28 point values for each date 
the only issue I only have the last print out of the reslut only.  @N1B4